# Converting matrix to graph, to eventually create adjacency matrix

Tags: matrix, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I've created a matrix with approximately 290 rows (regions) and approximately 630 columns (technology classes). I want to create a technology class - technology class adjacency matrix, because I want to compute relatedness and relatedness.density meausures using the EconGeo package.

I've read that I first need to convert my matrix into a graph, but when I try to do that I get the warning that my matrix isn't square.

My matrix looks like this:

Comment: the programme in which I perform the analysis is R

Answer (score 0):

The link to my matrix didn't came through, so here it is
[my matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anc0G.png)